# How to verify that the given function is a ring homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to answer this question and I'm completely stumped: "Determine if $f:\langle \mathbb{Z_3},+_{3},\cdotp_3\rangle \rightarrow \langle \mathbb{Z_{15}},+_{15},\cdotp_{15}\rangle$ where $f(x)=10x$ is a ring homomorphism." Do I go over each combination of elements $x,y$ in $\mathbb{Z_3}$ and see if they satisfy the homohorphism property?

Comment: I mean for example f(2+2 (mod3)) =10(1) = 2(10) + 2(10) (mod (15)) = 40 (mod 15) =10 = f(2) + f(2) (mod 15). This is what I roughly mean.

Comment: Usually a ring homomorphism is required to carry the multiplicative identity to the multiplicative identity, in which case you can say right away that $f$ doesn't do so.

Comment: Does it? All I know is that if 1 is the unity of R, then f(1) is the unity for f[R], given f is a ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've said in the comments, I'm assuming your ring homomorphisms are not required to take the multiplicative identity to multiplicative identity. In which case you just need to check three things:

1. Is $f$ well-defined?
2. $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.
3. $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$.

But (2.) and (3.) don't require checking these properties for every value of $x$ and $y$, if you can just verify them algebraically. Starting with (1.):

1. Suppose $x \equiv y \mod 3$. Then $x-y=3k$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$, and $10x-10y = 10(x-y) = 10(3k) = 30k \equiv 0 \mod 15$, so $10x \equiv 10y \mod 15$.
2. This follows directly from the distributive property: $f(x+y) = 10(x+y) = 10x+10y = f(x)+f(y)$.
3. Here we have $f(xy) = 10xy$, while $f(x)f(y) = 10x\cdot 10y = 10^2 xy$. In particular, with the values of $x=y=1$ this requires $10 \equiv 10^2 \mod 15$, and if we do have $10 \equiv 10^2 \mod 15$ then it follows that $10xy \equiv 10^2 xy \mod 15$ for all values of $x$ and $y$. So just verify the single equation $10 \equiv 10^2 \mod 15$, and you're done.

Comment: I'm sorry, what I had in mind originally is that $f(x +_3 y)=f(x) +_{15} f(y)$, so I'm thinking $10x+10y (mod 3) = 10x + 10y (mod 15) $ is what I have to show.

Comment: I understood what you meant. What you've written is not correct. If we're being strict, the definition $f(x) = 10x$ doesn't actually make sense; what you have to write is $f([x]_3) = [10x]_{15}$ for $x \in \mathbb Z$, where $[x]_3$ denotes the equivalence class of $x$ modulo $3$, and similarly for $[\bullet]_{15}$ (and then you need to verify (1.), that this definition doesn't depend on the choice of representative $x\in\mathbb Z$). Once (1.) has been verified, then you can write $f([x]_3+_3 [y]_3) = f([x+y]_3) = [10(x+y)]_{15} = [10x+10y]_{15}= [10x]_{15}+_{15}[10y]_{15} = f(x)+_{15}f(y)$.

Comment: Essentially, what I'm saying is we're just working with regular addition and multiplication of integers. As long as $f$ is well-defined, you won't get burned by doing this.